# Delimiter not found error - AWS Redshift Load from s3 using Kinesis Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am using Kinesis firehose to transfer data to Redshift via S3.
I have a very simple csv file that looks like this. The firehose puts it to s3 but Redshift errors out with Delimiter not found error.
I have looked at literally all posts related to this error but I made sure that delimiter is included.

**File**

```
GOOG,2017-03-16T16:00:01Z,2017-03-17 06:23:56.986397,848.78
GOOG,2017-03-16T16:00:01Z,2017-03-17 06:24:02.061263,848.78
GOOG,2017-03-16T16:00:01Z,2017-03-17 06:24:07.143044,848.78
GOOG,2017-03-16T16:00:01Z,2017-03-17 06:24:12.217930,848.78
```

OR

```
"GOOG","2017-03-17T16:00:02Z","2017-03-18 05:48:59.993260","852.12"
"GOOG","2017-03-17T16:00:02Z","2017-03-18 05:49:07.034945","852.12"
"GOOG","2017-03-17T16:00:02Z","2017-03-18 05:49:12.306484","852.12"
"GOOG","2017-03-17T16:00:02Z","2017-03-18 05:49:18.020833","852.12"
"GOOG","2017-03-17T16:00:02Z","2017-03-18 05:49:24.203464","852.12"
```

Redshift Table

```
CREATE TABLE stockvalue
( symbol                   VARCHAR(4),
  streamdate               VARCHAR(20),
  writedate                VARCHAR(26),
  stockprice               VARCHAR(6)
);
```

- Error
  [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBbEZ.jpg)
- Just in case, here's what my kinesis stream looks like
  [Firehose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvUq0.jpg)

Can someone point out what may be wrong with the file. 
I added a comma between the fields. 
All columns in destination table are varchar so there should be no reason for datatype error. 
Also, the column lengths match exactly between the file and redshift table. 
I have tried embedding columns in double quotes and without.

Comment: Can you post full COPY command you are using?

Comment: did you fix this? I'm having the same problem with data pipeline

Answer (score 6):

Can you post the full COPY command? It's cut off in the screenshot.

My guess is that you are missing `DELIMITER ','` in your COPY command. Try adding that to the COPY command.

Comment: will you please look at my question too... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017418/change-delimiter-to-pipe-in-aws-data-pipeline

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck on this for hours, and thanks to Shahid's answer it helped me solve it.

## Text Case for Column Names is Important

Redshift will always treat your table's columns as lower-case, so when mapping JSON keys to columns, **make sure the JSON keys are lower-case**, e.g.

### Your JSON file will look like:

```
{'id': 'val1', 'name': 'val2'}{'id': 'val1', 'name': 'val2'}{'id': 'val1', 'name': 'val2'}{'id': 'val1', 'name': 'val2'}
```

### And the COPY statement will look like

```sql
COPY latency(id,name) FROM 's3://<bucket-name>/<manifest>' CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/<role-name>' MANIFEST json 'auto';
```

Settings within Firehose must have the column names specified (again, in lower-case). Also, add the following to Firehose COPY options:

```sql
json 'auto' TRUNCATECOLUMNS blanksasnull emptyasnull
```

## How to call put_records from Python:

Below is a snippet showing how to use the put_records functions with kinesis in python:

'objects' passed into the 'put_to_stream' function is an array of dictionaries:

```py
def put_to_stream(objects):
    records = []

    for metric in metrics:
        record = {
            'Data': json.dumps(metric),
            'PartitionKey': 'swat_report'
        };

        records.append(record)

    print(records)

    put_response = kinesis_client.put_records(StreamName=kinesis_stream_name, Records=records)

flush
``
```

Comment: json 'auto' TRUNCATECOLUMNS blanksasnull emptyasnull was key for me, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1- You need to add FORMAT AS JSON 's3://yourbucketname/aJsonPathFile.txt'. AWS has not mentioned this already. Please note that this only works when your data is in JSON form like

{'attr1': 'val1', 'attr2': 'val2'} {'attr1': 'val1', 'attr2': 'val2'} {'attr1': 'val1', 'attr2': 'val2'} {'attr1': 'val1', 'attr2': 'val2'}

2- You also needs to verify the column order in kinesis firehouse and in csv file.and try adding

TRUNCATECOLUMNS blanksasnull emptyasnull

3- An example

COPY testrbl3 ( eventId,serverTime,pageName,action,ip,userAgent,location,plateform,language,campaign,content,source,medium,productID,colorCode,scrolltoppercentage) FROM 's3://bucketname/' CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam:::role/' MANIFEST json 'auto' TRUNCATECOLUMNS blanksasnull emptyasnull;